# How to create CMake library whose source code is stored in subdirectories?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to set a CMake project that builds a static library from sources that are stored in subdirectories. How to do it correctly, more flexible and to have possibility to add new files/directories in the future.

I have the following structure of directories for this library:

```
library\

      include\

            network\
                  socket.h
                  server.h
                  CMakeFiles.txt

            application.h
            CMakeFiles.txt

      src\
            network\
                  socket.cpp
                  server.cpp
                  CMakeFiles.txt

            application.cpp
            CMakeFiles.txt

      lib\
            (here should be a library.a file after compilation)

      CMakeFiles.txt
```

Comment: Why do you need a CMake in each subdirectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building a unique library, just have one CMakeLists.txt. You don't need one per folder. That would be the correct flexible way of handling your case.

One variable for the sources, one variable for the headers (used for the install procedure).

Comment: I was thinking about the only one variable for sources and one more for headers, but I thought this variable should be propagated somehow to each CMakeLists.txt in subdirectories, and these sub-CMakeLists.txt files should fill these variables out

Comment: Just list the files for each folder. That's what is recommended and you see your source files in one file, that's far more sustainable than several files adding source files to a common library.

Comment: @G-Virus There's [`FILE GLOB`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/file.html?highlight=glob) also to control collecting the source files.

Comment: Thank you, guys, it works. But please tell me again, why is it more preferred than separated files? Is it also good for the projects with many many files?

Comment: Yes, it's better, you have one central location where you know what you have included. You cannot forget a library. Also, when you move back from an `add_subdirectory`, you loose the variables you set, so you would need to hack this into your build process, which would not be pretty. Just use the rule of thumb 1 target = at most 1 file (meaning you can have several targets in one file).